# Stuck trying to access hash value

Tags: perl

I inherited a script and I need to be able to access some data from a hash. I want to be able to access the MB_Path value from the following.

```
$VAR1 = bless(
    {  
        'ME_Parts' => [
            bless(
                {  
                    'ME_Bodyhandle' => bless(
                        {  
                            'MB_Path' => '/tmp/msg-15072-1.txt'
                        },
                        'MIME::Body::File'
                    ),
                    'ME_Parts'       => [],
                    'mail_inet_head' => bless(
                        {  
                            'mail_hdr_foldlen' => 79,
                            'mail_hdr_modify'  => 0,
                            'mail_hdr_list'    => [
                                'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"',
                                'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable'
                            ],
                            'mail_hdr_hash' => {
                                'Content-Type' => [
                                    \$VAR1->{'ME_Parts'}[0]{'mail_inet_head'}
                                      {'mail_hdr_list'}[0]
                                ],
                                'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => [
                                    \$VAR1->{'ME_Parts'}[0]{'mail_inet_head'}
                                      {'mail_hdr_list'}[1]
                                ]
                            },
                            'mail_hdr_mail_from' => 'KEEP',
                            'mail_hdr_lengths'   => {}
                        },
                        'MIME::Head'
                    )
                },
                'MIME::Entity'
            ),
            bless(
                {  
                    'ME_Bodyhandle' => bless(
                        {   
                            'MB_Path' => '/tmp/msg-15072-2.html'
                        },  
                        'MIME::Body::File'
                    ),  
                    'ME_Parts'       => [], 
                    'mail_inet_head' => bless(
                        {   
                            'mail_hdr_foldlen' => 79, 
                            'mail_hdr_modify'  => 0,
                            'mail_hdr_list'    => [
                                'Content-Type: text/html;charset="us-ascii"',
                                'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable'
                            ],
                            'mail_hdr_hash' => {
                                'Content-Type' => [
                                    \$VAR1->{'ME_Parts'}[1]{'mail_inet_head'}
                                      {'mail_hdr_list'}[0]
                                ],
                                'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => [
                                    \$VAR1->{'ME_Parts'}[1]{'mail_inet_head'}
                                      {'mail_hdr_list'}[1]
                                ]
                            },
                            'mail_hdr_mail_from' => 'KEEP',
                            'mail_hdr_lengths'   => {}
                        },
                        'MIME::Head'
                    )
                },
                'MIME::Entity'
            )
        ],
        'ME_Epilogue'    => [],
        'ME_Preamble'    => [],
        'mail_inet_head' => bless(
            {
                'mail_hdr_foldlen' => 79,
                'mail_hdr_modify'  => 0,
                'mail_hdr_list'    => [
'Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary="----_=_NextPart_002_01CEB949.DC6B0180"'
                ],
                'mail_hdr_hash' => {
                    'Content-Type' =>
                      [ \$VAR1->{'mail_inet_head'}{'mail_hdr_list'}[0] ]
                },
                'mail_hdr_mail_from' => 'KEEP',
                'mail_hdr_lengths'   => {}
            },
            'MIME::Head'
        )
    'MIME::Entity'
);
```

I thought I could simply do the following

```
print $ent->parts->($i)->{ME_Bodyhandle}->{MB_Path};
```

However when I do that I get and error that the value is not initialized. But when I do dump of just `$ent->parts->($i)` I get the above code.

I am just stuck on this one.
Thanks,
Leo C

Comment: On another note, it would probably be cleaner to use accessor methods to access attributes of the object, rather than directly grab the values through the hash. [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a hash, you have an object (which happens to be implemented as a hash).  That's why the Data::Dumper output keeps saying `bless(...)`. You shouldn't be poking into its internals.

I think you're looking for

```
$ent->parts($i)->bodyhandle->path;
```

Answer (score 4):

Until you have exhausted the possibilities of the documentation, there is no excuse for dumping the underlying data structure that represents a Perl object and hard-coding access to its components. The rules of encapsulation apply to Perl object-oriented programming just as much as any other language.

The documentation for 
[`MIME::Entity`](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME%3a%3aEntity)
and
[`MIME::Body`](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME%3a%3aBody)
is quite clear, and the code you need is something like this

```
for my $part ($ent->parts) {
  my $path = $part->bodyhandle->path;
  print $path, "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
/tmp/msg-15072-1.txt
/tmp/msg-15072-2.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
print $ent->parts->($i)->{ME_Parts}->[$i]->{ME_Bodyhandle}->{MB_Path};
```